# how to show message success after write file on php?

Tags: php

i have a function which can write image on server folder with PHP. i follow instruction on this link [Can't save a HTML5 Canvas as Image on a server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34762882/cant-save-a-html5-canvas-as-image-on-a-server) , my problem is, i want to show success message when image save. on my code, it just show message only when write image failed. here is my function :

```
$loc = $_POST['lokasi'];
    define('UPLOAD_DIR', $loc);
 $filename =  $_POST['nama-file'];
 $img = $_POST['img'];
 $img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $img);
 $img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
 $data = base64_decode($img);
 $file = UPLOAD_DIR ;
 $success = file_put_contents($file, $data);
 print $success ? $file : 'Unable to save the file.';
```

thanks for your response. :)

Comment: Does the file upload successfully? Is the `$loc` accessible & writable?

Comment: yes, file upload successfully, but not show success message?

Comment: is it secure? when user can direct write image on server folder?

Comment: *is it secure?* It depends how do you limit your user to access this script and what are the limits of uploading (in terms of size). Watch out, `base64_decode()` is a common exploit to hack into system.

Comment: okay. i would noted it, thank you for your advice :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$loc = $_POST['lokasi'];
define('UPLOAD_DIR', $loc);
$filename =  $_POST['nama-file'];
$img = $_POST['img'];
$img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $img);
$img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
$data = base64_decode($img);
$file = UPLOAD_DIR ;    
if (file_put_contents($file, $data)) {
    echo "Image saved";
} else {
    echo "Unable to save the file.";
}
```

Note: With file-uploads its better to use move_uploaded_file

Comment: i try to modify it and combine with javascript like this : if (file_put_contents($file, $data)) {
    echo '<script language="javascript">';
echo 'alert("message successfully sent")';
echo '</script>';
} else {
    echo "Unable to save the file.";
}                but why still no alert? is it because i code it on yii component ???

Comment: But do you get the "Unable to save the file" message? Because the script looks fine.. I tested and it worked normally

Comment: no, i get feedback "image saved" message, but i must see it with firebug. when i dont use firebug, i never get message anything. is it because i used yii ?

Comment: i try it without framework, it works well, but why on yii controller doesn't show anything :|?

Comment: I personally dont use yii myself and have never used it before, so i cant tell you. But because you do get the message Image saved, it look like you did'nt saved it correctly or something?

Comment: my image save with no problem, i think it because yii controller doesn't allow direct javascript.