# compressing image in client side in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, image, codeigniter, canvas

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <form  action="<?php echo base_url();?>product-compress" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return handleFiles()" >
            <input type="file" name="images" value="" id="imagefile" class="btn btn-default">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"  class="btn btn-default">
            <input type="hidden" id="my_hidden" name="my_hidden" value="">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<img src="" id="image">
<script>

    function handleFiles()
    {
        var filesToUpload = document.getElementById("imagefile").files;
        var file = filesToUpload[0];
        // Create an image
        var img = document.createElement("img");
        // Create a file reader
        var reader = new FileReader();
        // Set the image once loaded into file reader
        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');

        reader.onload = function (e)
        {
            img.src = e.target.result;

            //var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
            //var canvas = $("<canvas>", {"id":"testing"})[0];
            var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
            ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

            var MAX_WIDTH = 400;
            var MAX_HEIGHT = 300;
            var width = img.width;
            var height = img.height;

            if (width > height) {
                if (width > MAX_WIDTH) {
                    height *= MAX_WIDTH / width;
                    width = MAX_WIDTH;
                }
            } else {
                if (height > MAX_HEIGHT) {
                    width *= MAX_HEIGHT / height;
                    height = MAX_HEIGHT;
                }
            }
            canvas.width = width;
            canvas.height = height;
            var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
            ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height);

            var dataurl = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
            document.getElementById('image').src = dataurl;
        };
        // Load files into file reader
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        document.getElementById('my_hidden').value = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');

        return true;


        // Post the data
        /*
         var fd = new FormData();
         fd.append("name", "some_filename.jpg");
         fd.append("image", dataurl);
         fd.append("info", "lah_de_dah");
         */
    }

</script>
```

Server Side Code :

```
public function product_compress() {

        $upload_dir = "uploads/products/images/";  //implement this function yourself
        $img = $_POST['my_hidden'];
//        echo $upload_dir."<br>";
//        print_r($img);exit;
        $img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $img);        
        $img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
        $data = base64_decode($img);
        $file = $upload_dir .time()."image_name.jpg";
        $success = file_put_contents($file, $data);

        //if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image1"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
//        header('Location: image-testing');
    }
```

I got all this from stackoverflow with search for compressing a image in client side. Now i am getting a result of black colored image.
 It seems like i missing something for image to compress. No particular type of image conditions . if the image size 5mb i wanted into be reduced using canvas and i have find the maximum part from here

Comment: Not sure how is really your code, but do you understand that everything in your FileReader's `onload` event is asynchronous ? This means that your `// Post the data` will occur before the FileReader even finished reading the file, and thus before the image is drawn. Also, if you can give the link of the answer where you copy pasted this code from, it would need a comment : As your filereader's `onload`, your `img`s one is also async, which means that when you call `drawImage`, there are like 40% chances that the browser didn't loaded it yet, thus making your call completely useless.

Comment: Thank you for responding . Yes mostly i got the idea from stackoverflow. I will share those links to you. if you change the (return false;) you can view the images .But only if i try to move the file to server. I'm getting a black colored image.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10333971/html5-pre-resize-images-before-uploading
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13198131/how-to-save-a-html5-canvas-as-image-on-a-server

Comment: There are already a few comments pointing the lack of onload on the first answer of the first link. For the seconf link, everything there should be fine. But, it is way easier to send a Blob directly to the server : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34711715/phpjs-how-to-do-fileuploads-in-html-form-as-content-type-multipart-via-js/34713226#34713226