# Uploading image created from canvas

Tags: javascript, php, canvas

I'm trying to create an img object from canvas element and upload the image to the server:

```
  var img = new Image();
  img.src = c2.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 0.95);  // c2 is the canvas element
  var formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('img', img);
  $.ajax({
      url: 'pro01.php',
      cache:false,
      contentType: false,
      processData: false,
      type: 'post',
      data: formData,
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
      }
  });
```

**pro01.php**

```
$img = $_FILES['img'];
$target_dir = "images/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["img"]["name"]);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["img"]["tmp_name"], $target_file);
```

Console:
`<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: img in...`

Any help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP+JS: How to do Fileuploads in HTML Form as Content-Type Multipart (via JS)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34711715/phpjs-how-to-do-fileuploads-in-html-form-as-content-type-multipart-via-js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead on making it an image just convert the canvas to `base64`:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
```

Now send it:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "pro01.php",
  data: { 
     imgBase64: dataURL
  }
```

To receive it in php (**pro01.php**):

Get it from the post request, remove the start and call `base64_decode()` on the posted value:

```
$img = $_POST['imgBase64'];
$img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $img);
$img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
$fileData = base64_decode($img);
//saving
$fileName = 'photo.png';
file_put_contents($fileName, $fileData);
```

Comment: Hm, are you sure? What to do on php side with the `imgBase64` ?

Comment: Still a problem on php side. What about `basename`, `tmp_name`... Could you please write the rest of php code.

Comment: @bonaca try that code it saved it to a file. I forgot to remove the data at the start.

Comment: `photo.png` is created, but it has 0 kb. No preview, just empty file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137901/discussion-between-noah-cristino-and-bonaca).

Comment: I fixed the code. The POST was $_POST['data']; but it needed to be $_POST['imgBase64'];